# Creating new Rails app - Dependency API down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems, dependencies

I'm trying to create new Rails app:

```
rails new NewRailsApp
```

and keep getting an error:

```
  create
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  ...
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
     run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
Fetching full source index from https://rubygems.org/
Could not reach https://rubygems.org/
```

Is the error on my side or is it caused by Rubygems Dependecy API being down? (it has been down for four days according to [this](http://status.rubygems.org/))

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: This is completely unrelated to Windows7. Instead of closing the question, which is perfectly valid, one should try to clarify the exact reach of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temporarily use

```
source "http://bundler-api.herokuapp.com"
```

in your `Gemfile`.

Source: http://hone.herokuapp.com/bundler%20heroku/2012/10/22/rubygems-and-the-dependency-api.html